# Add multiple permissions to account in EOS

Tags: cleos, eosio-code, permissions, eosio.cdt

When I try to set a single permission, it is working fine:

```
cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io set account permission market active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "MARKET PUBLIC KEY","weight": 1}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"market","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p market
```

and the result is as follows:

**warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet**

meaning that the change has completed successfully, but when I try the same syntax to set multiple permissions to the same account like this:

```
cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io set account permission market active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "MARKET PUBLIC KEY","weight": 1}],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"market","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1},{"permission":{"actor":"token","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight”:1},]}’ owner -p market
```

nothing happens. No JSON parsing errors. When I check using:

```
cleos --url https://jungle2.cryptolions.io get account market
```

only the initially set `eosio.code` permission is available.

Any ideas and suggestions about the syntax of the JSON, I am using to set multiple permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a working solution, using different syntax:

```
cleos set account permission market active market --add-code
cleos set account permission market active token --add-code
```

account permissions:

```
{
  "account_name": "market",
  ...
  "permissions": [{
      "perm_name": "active",
      "parent": "owner",
      "required_auth": {
        "threshold": 1,
        "keys": [{
            "key": "market public key",
            "weight": 1
          }
        ],
        "accounts": [{
            "permission": {
              "actor": "market",
              "permission": "eosio.code"
            },
            "weight": 1
          },{
            "permission": {
              "actor": "token",
              "permission": "eosio.code"
            },
            "weight": 1
          }
        ],
        "waits": []
      }
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```